# It only shows the first data. How can I show every data with the same id?

Tags: php, laravel

This code only shows the `first` data it finds.

```
public function getGroupInfo($eg_id){
        $members = \App\EventGroupMembers::where('eg_id', '=', $eg_id)->get();
        if ($members->count() > 0) {
            $user = \App\User::find($members[0]->user_id);
            echo $user->first_name;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Table `event_group_members`

```
eg_id      user_id
1          1
2          2
2          3
3          4
3          5
```

Table `user`

```
user_id    first_name
1          tony
2          steve
3          bruce
4          thor
5          clint
```

What should I do to show all the `first_names` with the same `eg_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($members as $member)
{
    echo $member->id;
    // It will echo diff id for each iteration
}
```

Explanation: $member is an Std class object that have more than one value, if you are using this:

```
$members[0]->user_id;
```

means you are referring its 0th index value. To access all value you have to use loop.

Comment: Hey it shows only the IDs but the name did not. And if I use **echo $member->first_name;** it won't show anything

Comment: foreach ($members as $member) {
   $user = \App\User::where('user_id', '=', $member->user_id)->value('first_name');

Comment: @Noob, this solution will create N+1 queries, ad that will kill your app. If there are 20000 users in the table, app will run 20001 DB queries. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Thank you for your help @alexey

Comment: @Noob, yes, your code from comment above will do N+1 queries to DB. Never use this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
 public function getGroupInfo($eg_id){
        $userNames = array();
        $members = \App\EventGroupMembers::where('eg_id', '=', $eg_id)->get();
        if ($members->count() > 0) {
        foreach($members as $data){
        $user = \App\User::where('user_id',$data->user_id)->get();

        foreach($user as $userData){
        $userNames[] = $userData->first_name;
        }
        }         
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**And then you can retrieve user names from that array.**

```
foreach($userNames as $name){
echo $name;
}
```

Comment: This will create N+1 queries. If there are 20000 users in the table, app will run 20001 DB queries. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Thanks for the info. I will keep this in mind next time I run such operation.

Answer (score 0):

You have `user_id` in `EventGroupMembers` model, so it seems you're working with App which already has [one-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) between `EventGroupMembers` and `User` models. So, check [foreign key](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) in `event_group_members` table migration and relation in `User` model.

```
public function eventGroupMembers()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

After that you can filter users by `eg_id` in `EventGroupMembers`model:

```
$members = User::with(['eventGroupMembers' => function($q) use ($eg_id) {
    $q->where('eg_id', $eg_id);
})->get();
```

This solution will do just two queries to a DB.

Then just list users' first names in blade template:

```
@foreach ($members)
    $member->first_name;
@endforeach
```